# Out-of-fold vs training error in caret

Tags: r, r-caret

Using cross validation in model tuning, I get different error rates from `caret::train`'s `results` object and calculating the error myself on its `pred` object. I'd like to understand why they differ, and ideally how to use out-of-fold error rates for model selection, plotting model performance, etc.

The `pred` object contains out-of-fold predictions. The docs are pretty clear that `trainControl(..., savePredictions = "final")` saves out-of-fold predictions for the best hyperparameter values: "an indicator of how much of the hold-out predictions for each resample should be saved... "final" saves the predictions for the optimal tuning parameters." (Keeping "all" predictions and then filtering to the best tuning values doesn't resolve the issue.)

The `train` docs say that the `results` object is "a data frame the training error rate..." I'm not sure what that means, but the values for the best row are consistently different from the metrics calculated on `pred`. Why do they differ and how can I make them line up?

```r
d <- data.frame(y = rnorm(50))
d$x1 <- rnorm(50, d$y)
d$x2 <- rnorm(50, d$y)
train_control <- caret::trainControl(method = "cv",
                                     number = 4,
                                     search = "random",
                                     savePredictions = "final")
m <- caret::train(x = d[, -1],
                     y = d$y,
                     method = "ranger",
                     trControl = train_control,
                     tuneLength = 3)
#> Loading required package: lattice
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
m
#> Random Forest 
#> 
#> 50 samples
#>  2 predictor
#> 
#> No pre-processing
#> Resampling: Cross-Validated (4 fold) 
#> Summary of sample sizes: 38, 36, 38, 38 
#> Resampling results across tuning parameters:
#> 
#>   min.node.size  mtry  splitrule   RMSE       Rsquared   MAE      
#>   1              2     maxstat     0.5981673  0.6724245  0.4993722
#>   3              1     extratrees  0.5861116  0.7010012  0.4938035
#>   4              2     maxstat     0.6017491  0.6661093  0.4999057
#> 
#> RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
#> The final values used for the model were mtry = 1, splitrule =
#>  extratrees and min.node.size = 3.
MLmetrics::RMSE(m$pred$pred, m$pred$obs)
#> [1] 0.609202
MLmetrics::R2_Score(m$pred$pred, m$pred$obs)
#> [1] 0.642394
```

Created on 2018-04-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RMSE for cross validation is not calculated the way you show, but rather for each fold and then averaged. Full example:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(y = rnorm(50))
d$x1 <- rnorm(50, d$y)
d$x2 <- rnorm(50, d$y)
train_control <- caret::trainControl(method = "cv",
                                     number = 4,
                                     search = "random",
                                     savePredictions = "final")
set.seed(1)
m <- caret::train(x = d[, -1],
                  y = d$y,
                  method = "ranger",
                  trControl = train_control,
                  tuneLength = 3)
#output
Random Forest 

50 samples
 2 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (4 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 37, 38, 37, 38 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  min.node.size  mtry  splitrule   RMSE       Rsquared   MAE      
   8             1     extratrees  0.6106390  0.4360609  0.4926629
  12             2     extratrees  0.6156636  0.4294237  0.4954481
  19             2     variance    0.6472539  0.3889372  0.5217369

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were mtry = 1, splitrule = extratrees and min.node.size = 8.
```

RMSE for best model is `0.6106390`

Now calculate the RMSE for each fold and average:

```
m$pred %>%
  group_by(Resample) %>%
  mutate(rmse = caret::RMSE(pred, obs)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(rmse)) %>%
  pull(mean) %>%
  mean
#output
0.610639

m$pred %>%
  group_by(Resample) %>%
  mutate(rmse = MLmetrics::RMSE(pred, obs)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(rmse)) %>%
  pull(mean) %>%
  mean
#output
0.610639
```

Answer (score 1):

I get different results. This is apparently a random process.

```
MLmetrics::RMSE(m$pred$pred, m$pred$obs)
[1] 0.5824464
> MLmetrics::R2_Score(m$pred$pred, m$pred$obs)
[1] 0.5271595
```

If you want a random (more accurately a pseudo-random process to be reproducible, then use set.seed immediately prior to the call.

Comment: The question is about consistency of metrics within an episode of model training, not consistency across training runs.

Comment: `ranger` has a `seed` option that will help (but nobody set here)